# How to change this Access SQL to select similar rather than identical records

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-like, dropdownbox

The following code works, as I type data the Dropdown is populated with fewer and fewer records until either only one remains, or I click to select a record from a small number of records.  However sometimes I click the wrong name e.g. John Jones rather than John Smith and then the Comment_Enter() code just populates the Dropdown with John Jones; how can I change the code so the LIKE selection ignores the last few (or x) characters in the record string, to populate the Dropdown with a few records surrounding the one I really want to select?

```vb
Private Sub Comment_Change()

Dim strRowSource As String

   If Len(Me!Comment.Text) > 2 Then 'when more than 2 characters are entered the following code runs
        strRowSource = "SELECT DISTINCT [Purchase ledger].Comment FROM [Purchase ledger]"
        
        strRowSource = strRowSource & " WHERE Comment Like '"
        strRowSource = strRowSource & Me!Comment.Text
        strRowSource = strRowSource & "*'"
        
        Me!Comment.RowSource = strRowSource
        Me!Comment.Dropdown
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub Comment_Enter()

Dim strRowSource As String

    If Len(Me!Comment.Text) > 2 Then 'when more than 2 characters are entered the following code runs
        strRowSource = "SELECT DISTINCT [Purchase ledger].Comment FROM [Purchase ledger]"

        strRowSource = strRowSource & " WHERE Comment Like '"
        strRowSource = strRowSource & Me!Comment.Text
        strRowSource = strRowSource & "*'"
        
        Me!Comment.RowSource = strRowSource
        Me!Comment.Dropdown
    End If
End Sub
```

Nothing as I do not understand exactly how the LIKE selection works; I adapted it from elsewhere.

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for: [Soundex function in MS Access VBA](http://msaccess.erpmakers.com/Articles_MSAccess/0067-soundex%20function%20in%20microsoft%20access%20vba.php) or [Soundex - Fuzzy matches](http://allenbrowne.com/vba-Soundex.html).

Comment: Also you could use regular expressions, for instance, since you can use public functions in a code module just about anywhere try this: http://www.icodeguru.com/database/access.hacks/0596009240/accesshks-chp-5-sect-16.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give a strict answer to your question, this example.
If the length of the filter string is longer than 6 characters, this code will add results to the search that match the given string minus the 3 last characters:

```
   strRowSource = strRowSource & " WHERE Comment Like '"
   strRowSource = strRowSource & Me!Comment.Text
   strRowSource = strRowSource & "*' "
   if(not isnull(Me!Comment.Text) and len(Me!Comment.Text) > 6) then        
    strRowSource = strRowSource & " OR Comment Like '" & left(Me!Comment.Text, len(Me!Comment.Text)-3)
    strRowSource = strRowSource & "*' "
   end if
```